# How to show content in bash using hash key(#)?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

What I exactly want to do is make the bash script outputs using hash keys(#) to emphasize the info on terminal screen. I would appreciate your help with any tricks.

as below shows,

```
 #########
     #
     #
     #
     #
     #
 #########
```

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work about it?  `printf` or `echo` will likely help you (though often [`printf` is preferred](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo))

Comment: You have a criteria for fixed length in x & y-axis based on any input say 10?

Comment: check `banner` command if its there in  your box.

Comment: This question has already been answered, first post in google [ASCII art generator](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69271/ascii-art-generator)

Comment: @PS. Oh..Yeah...Amazing tools. Thanks so much.

Comment: @EricRenouf, Em....Actually I intend to apply a more handy tool like 'banner' instead of using 'echo' or 'printf' to output manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a command (not installed by default), which does something like you want, it is named "banner".

Example:

```
$ banner HELLO
#     # ####### #       #       #######
#     # #       #       #       #     #
#     # #       #       #       #     #
####### #####   #       #       #     #
#     # #       #       #       #     #
#     # #       #       #       #     #
#     # ####### ####### ####### #######
```

The Ubuntu package is `sysvbanner`

Comment: `++` available in Mac OS X too!

Comment: Could add a point that it supports the `width` option with `-w` flag

Comment: @Zumo de Vidrio，it works for me now, thanks for your tips.

Comment: @All, Wow...I just found an interesting website about this solution, and it provides more kinds of characters you want using as the elements. http://www.network-science.de/ascii/                                               Enjoying